# Clean way to import data from a text file?

Tags: java, text

I have a text file with the following in it:

> name1:0|0|0|0|0|
>   name2:0|0|0|0|0|
>   ... etc

I'm importing the names into an array of Strings.

That's fine, however I can't think of a clean way to associate the numbers with the array item. The numbers are separated by a "pipe" '|' character

Ideally I'd like to call a method which returns an array of Integers when given the name i.e. something like `public int[] getScores(String name)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [string split](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

First use `:` to split a line, then use `|` to split out each number as a string. At last use Integer.Parse to get the numbers.

Comment: I ended up using a combination of this and 2D arrays... thanks!

Comment: Most likely, you'd be better off using a HashMap<String, int[]> than a 2D array.  That should get you your 'ideal' method call that you describe above.

Answer (score 6):

[Scanner](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) can also do it (since Java 1.5). The advantages over [String#split](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) is that you get some sort of automatic type conversion using regular expressions.

Example from javadoc

```
String input = "1 fish 2 fish red fish blue fish";
Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\s*fish\\s*");
System.out.println(s.nextInt());
System.out.println(s.nextInt());
System.out.println(s.next());
System.out.println(s.next());
s.close();
```

Also, if your aim is to recover the numbers by their name, use some kind of hash table to store it for faster retrieval.

Comment: Yes- a hashtable with the name as the key, and the array of ints as the values.